# $(document) event handling in vue 2 component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, dom, dom-events

I have some vue 2 component:

```
<template>
    <section class="component" v-if="load">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="loader" v-else>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "myApp",
    data() {
        return {
            load: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.initApp();
    },
    methods: {
        initApp() {
            this.load = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and I init it like this (little use of jquery)

```
if ($('#container').length > 0) {
    new Vue({
        components: {
            myApp
        },
        render: (h) => {
            return h(myApp);
        },
    }).$mount('#container');
}
```

Also I have global document's custom event in other non-vue code, triggered by jquery:

```
$(document).trigger('someEvent');
```

How can I handle this document's **someEvent** in **myApp** component to fully reload it? (This event requires full updating of content and data in myApp.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have u tried on mounted hook

```
mounted(){
document.addEventListener("someEvent", ()=>{

//your code after listening to the event 

}); 
}
```